# cmd+del acts like opt+cmd+del

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

For some unknown reason my Mac deletes permanently when I hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd>. Normally <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> is to move to Trash and <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> is the one to delete for good. Can't figure out how to make it work 'normal' again?

Comment: What happens if you drag-n-drop something to Trash icon in Dock?

Comment: Unfortunately the same behaviour. In both cases I get the warning msg saying that the deletion will be permanent.

Comment: Also strange because I didn't installed any new sw. It was good yesterday.

Comment: In System Restore / Modifer Keys I tried to Restore to Defaults, but since I haven't change any keys, nothing happens too.

Comment: "Unfortunately the same behaviour." - that means you have a problem with a Trash, not with hot keys

Comment: Try this one: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3776862?tstart=0

Comment: Thanks, that thread solved the issue. More precisely the Terminal cmd: sudo rm -rvf /Users/{YOURHOME}/.Trash; killall Finder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your trash folder is broken. There are a lot of [solutions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3776862?tstart=0) of this problem in the internet, but in short you may need to remove your trash folder `sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash` and let Finder create a new one by restarting your Mac.